# Inheritance of toString()

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I have a method `toString()` which is not being inherited from `Shape`. Why?

```
function Shape(){
  this.name = 'shape';
  this.toString = function() {return this.name;};
}

function TwoDShape(){
  this.name = '2D shape';
}

function Triangle(side, height) {
  this.name = 'Triangle';
  this.side = side;
  this.height = height;
  this.getArea = function(){return this.side * this.height / 2;};
}

TwoDShape.prototype = TwoDShape;
Triangle.prototype = Triangle;

TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;

var my = new Triangle(5, 10);

document.write("my getarea: " + my.getArea() + "my name is: " + my.toString()  + "<br>");​
```

[Demo jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/WCzEz/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Triangle`'s prototype must be a `Shape` so that it inherits its methods:

```
Triangle.prototype = new Shape();
```

More specifically, since you have multiple levels of inheritance:

```
TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape();
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;

Triangle.prototype = new TwoDShape();
Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;
```

That is, `TwoDShape` inherits `Shape`, and `Triangle` inherits from `TwoDShape`.

Generically, if `Foo` inherits `Bar`, you'd have:

```
Foo.prototype = new Bar(); // inherit Bar
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo; // Fix constructor which now points to Bar
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c4AwH/)**.

#### References:

- [MDN: Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript: Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance)
- [OOP in JavaScript: Inheritance](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html)

Comment: Actually, Triangle should inherit from TwoDShape and TwoDShape should inherit from Shape. Therefore, you need something like: `TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape; Triangle.prototype = new TwoDShape;` In this case, there's no visible difference since TwoDShape only changes the name and Triangle overrides the name as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the prototype of your shades to Shade, not to TwoDShape or Triangle like you do.

Comment: The example is given by Joao Silva. But if you need it here again you have to do something like `TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape;`

Answer (score 0):

Prototype inheritance should be `SubConstructor.prototype = new ParentConstructor`, not `SubConstructor.prototype = ParentConstructor`. You're not inheriting the prototype correctly, so you don't inherit the `toString` method; `getArea` is not a prototype method, but a actual property of each instance, so it works.